# Rounding datetime objects to a given granularity

Tags: date-and-time

How does one round datetime objects to any granularity (eg "Hour","Minute" etc)?

What I'm looking for is a function that would do the following:

```
DateRound[DateObject[{2018, 7, 7, 10, 55, 42.}], "Hour"]

-> DateObject[{2018, 7, 7, 11, 0, 0.}]

DateRound[DateObject[{2018, 7, 7, 10, 55, 42.}], "Minute"]

-> DateObject[{2018, 7, 7, 10, 56, 0.}]
```

That is, round the given DateObject to whatever granularity is given - the nearest minute, nearest hour, day, month etc.

I can *Floor* dates using `CurrentDate`:

```
CurrentDate[DateObject[{2018, 7, 7, 10, 55, 42.}], "Hour"]

-> DateObject[{2018, 7, 7, 10}]
```

or by using `DateValue`:

```
DateValue[DateObject[{2018, 7, 7, 10, 55, 42.}], {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour"}]

-> {2018, 7, 7, 10}
```

but as you can see, this does not give me the *rounded* granularity (11), but the *floored* granularity (10).

I know about `DayRound`, which is approximately the functionality I'm looking for, but it doesn't support any time operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `DatePlus` handles adding fractional units properly (which I'm pretty sure it does), I would try adding half the unit you want and then doing the floor operation that `CurrentDate` does. It works for your examples.

```
dateRound[d_, s_] := CurrentDate[DatePlus[d, {.5, s}], s]
```